# Semicolon on command line in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am running my application in linux by providing inputs as command line. My input field contain an argument which contains ";"(semicolon) internally.(For example:123;434;5464). 
This will be parsed using UTF8String encode and send. 
But when i am using like this, in initial itself i am getting,

```
 bash: 434: command not found
 bash: 5464: command not found
```

And when i capture traffic the output contains only 123 instead 123;434;5464
But if i give without semicolon (Ex:123:434:5464),not getting any problem output coming properly as 123:434:5464

Point me how to give command line input by using semicolon as to come output. Is there any particular syntax to use while doing with semicolon.
I am running like below

```
./runASR.sh -ip 10.78.242.4 -port 3868 -sce 10.78.241.206 -id 85;167838865;1385433280
```

where -id field contain that value with issue.

Answer (score 43):

`;` is treated an *end of command* character. So `123;456;5464` to bash is in fact 3 commands. To pass such meta-characters escape it with escape character `\`.

```
./command 123\;456\;5464
```

Or Just quote it with single quote ([double quote evaluates the inner string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/376535)) (Thanks Triplee, I forgot to mention this)

```
./command '123;456;5464'
```

Comment: Double quotes would actually work fine here (but single quotes are generally better); you worry about `$` and back-tick symbols inside double quotes.

Comment: does the following command waits until the previous command finished to execute?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 The command after `;` doesn't execute until the execution of the command at the left side of `;` is done.