# Why is my script not printing output on one line?

Tags: sql, bash, shell, sh

[This is an image of what I'm asking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoeNP.png)
I am using the following -echo- in a script and after I execute, the output format is as shown below:

```
`echo -e "UPDATE table1 SET table1_f1='$Fname' ,table1_f2='$Lname' where table1_f3='$id';\ncommit;" >> $OutputFile`
```

output: `UPDATE table1 SET table1_f1='Fname' ,table1_f2='Lname' where table1_f3='id ';`
the `';` is appearing on a new line, why is that happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233998/2955337
; is treated an end of command character. escape it with a backslash

Comment: Could you clarify the question and source a bit. I think some is missing or conflicting with the SO formatting. The `;` you say is on a lower line, isn't shown at all here. It's not clear (to me) if the very first backtick character is part of the script line or not, as the character has special meaning both in scripts and here on SO. Also, by *"echo on a script"*, i imagine you mean *"echo inside a script"* ?

Comment: @sleepyhead It's inside a quoted string, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `$id` contains a newline.

Comment: @Raxi I provided a screenshot of the problem, and yes echo inside a script

Comment: @Barmar $id is referring to a variable

Comment: Please format the codes in your description properly.

Comment: @konsolebox I provided a screenshot of the codes, can please check it.

Comment: Yeah but looks like somebody gave you the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$id` in your shell script actually contains that newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) at the end; so there isn't really anything wrong in the part of the script you've shown here.

This effect is pretty common if the variable is created based on external commands (update:) or by `read`ing external files as you are here.

For simple values, one way to strip the newline off the end of the value, prior to using it in your `echo` is:

```
id=$( echo "${id}" | tr -s '\r' '' | tr -s '\n' '' );
```

or for scripts that already rely on a particular bash `IFS` value:

```
OLDIFS="${IFS}"; 
IFS=$'\n\t '; 
id=$( echo "${id}" | tr -s '\r' '' | tr -s '\n' '' );
IFS="${OLDIFS}";
```

Comment: I tried to set `IFS=$'\n';` but the issue is still there.

Comment: This is how I am defining the `id` variable: `while IFS='|'; read  Fname Lname id`
It get its value from the input file

Comment: does the input all look like `A|B|C` ? or can there be more `|`

Comment: and try:    `while IFS=$'\n|'; read  Fname Lname id`

Comment: It is `A|B|C`, I am using one pipe between every value

Comment: I tried `while IFS=$'\n|'; read  Fname Lname id` as you suggested and still got the same issue :(

Comment: Try adding `id="$( echo ${id} )";` inside that loop (so ~2 lines lower; the line after `do`)

Comment: `do`
`echo -e "UPDATE table1 SET table1_f1='$Fname' ,table1_f2='$Lname' where table1_f3='$id';\ncommit;" >> $OutputFile` where exactly?

Comment: above your `echo` line

Comment: still the same issue, it seems like there is a problem with the input file; although I have seen other scripts with similar input files working fine.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Raxi, if I find any solution I will update here.

Comment: Strange, it works for me when i cobble these bits together; 1 more thing you could try is: `OLDIFS="${IFS}"; IFS=$'\n\t '; id=$( echo ${id} | tr -s '\r' '' | tr -s '\n' '' ); IFS="${OLDIFS}";` (again, placing it inside the loop, just before your `echo -e "UPDATE...`

Comment: @Omar Yahya I suggest opening another question about why your `id` variable stores a newline. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: It worked but the id is not between `''`, all the output on one line but the id was ignored. As I said I think the problem is with the input file as I get the data from an Excel sheet and copy it to a txt file. I use notepad++ to prepare my input file

Comment: I think it was just that there was a `\r\n` newline in the file (windows style). not just a `\n` (unix/linux style) as i expected earlier; but fundementally still the same problem. -- i'll update the answer with the working version